# Laravel search not returning any result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a search where user can search for book title. There is a field in 'books' table called 'title'.

however if I do dd($books); I get:

```
Collection {#667 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

If I do dd($searchTerms); output seems to be correct

Here's my controller:

```
    function search()
    {
        $books = Book::all();
        return view('layouts/search',['books' => $books]);
    }
        function details() {
            $searchTerms = explode(' ', \Request::input('book')); 
            $books = Book::where(function($q) use($searchTerms) {
            foreach ($searchTerms as $book) {
             $q->orWhere('title', '%'.$book.'%');
            }
        })->get();
            dd($books);
        return view('layouts/details', compact('books'));
}
```

Search blade:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')

@section('content')
    <h1>Search for books</h1>
    <form action="{{url('details')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <input type='text'  name='book' placeholder='Enter any character' />
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Search">
    </form>
@endsection
```

Details blade:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')

@section('content')
    <h1>User Details</h1>
      <form>
      <p>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($books as $book)
    <a href=  "{{url('reader/'.$book->title)}}">
      {{$book->title}}</a>
      </p>
</form>
@endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to tell the eloquent builder that your `OR`'s should have `LIKE` as the operator:

```
$q->orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.$book.'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the function of details to this

```
function details(Request $request) {
        $searchTerms = $request->book; 
        $books = Book::where(function($q) use($searchTerms) {
        foreach ($searchTerms as $book) {
         $q->orWhere('title', '%'.$book.'%');
        }
    })->get();
        dd($books);
    return view('layouts/details', compact('books'));
}
```